# Basic Plugin (NPAPI / npruntime) Hello world

Tags: plugins, npapi, npruntime

Backgound steps

1. Used Mozilla code from here: http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/modules/plugin/tools/sdk/samples/basic/windows/
2. New Empty Project in Visual Studio & added above files
3. Changed Congfiguration Type : Dynamic Library (.dll)
   3b. Linker->Input->Module Definition File: BasicPlugin.def
4. Commented BasicPlugin.cpp, to only have basic functions and disply a MessageBox for Hello World
5. Compile (successfull) & copied to Firefox Plugins directory
6. Checked about:plugins (found)
7. Load HTML to call dll (failed)

I am trying to use the npruntime files now and make a scriptible plugin (not sure how). But I dont understand why the plugin doesnt get loaded. This seems the basic of all basic. Any one have ideas on this?

**BasicPlugin.cpp**

```
#include "BasicPlugin.h"

NPError NP_Initialize(NPNetscapeFuncs* bFuncs, NPPluginFuncs* pFuncs)
{
MessageBox(NULL,"Hello World","NP_Initialize",MB_OK);

  // Check the size of the provided structure based on the offset of the last member we need.
  pFuncs->newp = NPP_New;
  pFuncs->destroy = NPP_Destroy;
  pFuncs->setwindow = NPP_SetWindow;
  pFuncs->newstream = NPP_NewStream;
  pFuncs->destroystream = NPP_DestroyStream;
  pFuncs->asfile = NPP_StreamAsFile;
  pFuncs->writeready = NPP_WriteReady;
  pFuncs->write = NPP_Write;
  pFuncs->print = NPP_Print;
  pFuncs->event = NPP_HandleEvent;
  pFuncs->urlnotify = NPP_URLNotify;
  pFuncs->getvalue = NPP_GetValue;
  pFuncs->setvalue = NPP_SetValue;

  return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
}

//NP_EXPORT(char*) NP_GetPluginVersion()
//{return PLUGIN_VERSION;}

//NP_EXPORT(const char*) NP_GetMIMEDescription()
//{return "application/basic-plugin:bsc:Basic plugin";}

NPError NP_GetValue(void* future, NPPVariable aVariable, void* aValue) 
{return NPERR_NO_ERROR;}

NPError OSCALL  NP_Shutdown()
{return NPERR_NO_ERROR;}

NPError NPP_New(NPMIMEType pluginType, NPP instance, uint16_t mode, int16_t argc, char* argn[], char* argv[], NPSavedData* saved) 
{
MessageBox(NULL,"Hello World","NPP_New",MB_OK);
return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
}

NPError NPP_Destroy(NPP instance, NPSavedData** save) 
{return NPERR_NO_ERROR;}

NPError NPP_SetWindow(NPP instance, NPWindow* window) 
{
MessageBox(NULL,"Hello World","NPP_SetWindow",MB_OK);
return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
}

NPError NPP_NewStream(NPP instance, NPMIMEType type, NPStream* stream, NPBool seekable, uint16_t* stype) 
{return NPERR_GENERIC_ERROR;}

NPError NPP_DestroyStream(NPP instance, NPStream* stream, NPReason reason) 
{return NPERR_GENERIC_ERROR;}

int32_t NPP_WriteReady(NPP instance, NPStream* stream) 
{return 0;}

int32_t NPP_Write(NPP instance, NPStream* stream, int32_t offset, int32_t len, void* buffer) 
{return 0;}

void NPP_StreamAsFile(NPP instance, NPStream* stream, const char* fname) {}

void NPP_Print(NPP instance, NPPrint* platformPrint)  {}
int16_t NPP_HandleEvent(NPP instance, void* event) 
{return 1;}

void NPP_URLNotify(NPP instance, const char* URL, NPReason reason, void* notifyData)  {}

NPError NPP_GetValue(NPP instance, NPPVariable variable, void *value) 
{return NPERR_GENERIC_ERROR;}

NPError NPP_SetValue(NPP instance, NPNVariable variable, void *value) 
{return NPERR_GENERIC_ERROR;}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
 <body>
  <center><h1>Basic Plugin Example for Mozilla Test Case</h1></center>
  This test case is to demonstrate the Basic Plugin example. You should get a message box saying Hello World.
  <br><br>
  <center><embed type="application/basic-plugin" border=1 width=600 height=40></center>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to run this on windows then it won't work; you have the wrong entrypoints for windows. The ones you have listed are the entrypoints for linux. See https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/PluginAuto/Win/np_winmain.cpp for FireBreath's windows entrypoints file; also explained in http://npapi.com/tutorial

**Edit**

Hypothetically there could be lots of other things; without seeing your whole project it's hard to speculate. It's showing up in about:plugins, so your strings resources are in place. Are you exporting the symbols correctly with your .def file? Does DllMain get called? (don't use a messagebox there, just log something or set a breakpoint)

Again, FireBreath is (aside from being a much easier way to create a NPAPI plugin) an example of creating a fully functioning npapi plugin; you may learn a lot from looking at it. If none of that works I couldn't begin to speculate without seeing your whole project; maybe as a github project or something?

Comment: So changing the entry points of NP_GetEntryPoints to:

NPError OSCALL NP_GetEntryPoints(NPPluginFuncs* pFuncs)


and NP_Initialize:

NPError FAR PASCAL NP_Initialize(NPNetscapeFuncs* pFuncs)                                did not solve it is there something else besides entry points?

Comment: Im not able to set a breakpoint, VS says there is not any symbols loaded.

Comment: Well the solution was that in VS I was not adding the def file to the linker. Thanks for the help!